# Connect to database with Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I run WAMP and have made the MySQL database but it cannot connect. Can anyone help me?

```
package databasetest;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 *
 * @author kon_f
 */
public class DataBaseTest {

    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private static final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasetest";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection conn = null;

        try{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Connected!");
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to load the Driver. If you use Google. you will find houndreds of examples

Comment: run:
Error: Could not find or load main class databasetest.DataBaseTest
C:\Users\kon_f\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: The second answer on this question is great for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database

Comment: @Jens loading the driver with `Class.forName` hasn't been necessary since Java 6.

Comment: its ok now i found the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out what was wrong.. it was just the stupid microsoft one drive.. i deleted it and changed the directory and now its ok thanks

Comment: its ok now i found the way

Answer (score 0):

Import the mysql jar file to the external jar directry

Comment: its ok now i found the way

Answer (score 0):

First You have to Load "**mysqlconnector.jar**" file into your Project.

and also load the driver into program

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: loading the driver with `Class.forName` hasn't been necessary since Java 6.

Comment: its ok now i found the way

Comment: its ok now i found the way